# Changing .env value on nextjs after build

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I create the application using next and I use .env for registering some endpoint to get data on my app.

this application can be installed on different clients, and that is why I need to create a .env file for setting the endpoint based on my client domain.

for example, i have 2 clients then on my .env file I create the variable name with API_ENDPOINT = a.domain.com

and I want to change this API_ENDPOINT variable on .env after I build this application. so the application can deploy everywhere my client server without the need to rebuild the app. all I need is just change the .env file.

so is it possible on nextjs? can you help me with the solution?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update env variables (for example API_ENDPOINT) **only with rebuild**.

Possible solutions for your issue (without re-build):

---

A. Create a config.json (or any filename you want) file in your root folder.

`config.json` contents:

```
//config.json
{
  "API_ENDPOINT": "https://api.example.com"
}
```

and

```
// utils/config.js
import configData from '../config.json';

//you can define your conditions here if(condition){} needed to take correct solution
const config = {
  API_ENDPOINT: configData.API_ENDPOINT
};

export default config;
```

so you can import your config in the code where you need the values:

```
import config from '../utils/config';
```

---

B. Using `router` of nextjs (frontend part only):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function MyComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const basePath = router.basePath;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Base Path: {basePath}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

---

C. Using basePath in middleware of nextjs (node side only):

```
//pages/api/middleware.js
export default (req, res) => {
  const { basePath } = req.next;
  console.log(`Base Path: ${basePath}`);

  // Your middleware logic here

  res.end();
};
```

---

But anyway, if you are using `vercel`, once you are changing `.env variables` on vercel, it will trigger manual rebuild on `vercel`.

P.S. these solutions are not native, the good thing is to optimize you code to easily update .env variables

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem changing env variables without having to rebuild the application. The problem is because Next.js hardcode the value at build time if the `process.env.SOMETHING` is accessed directly. A workaround to this is by dynamically accessing by a reference/variable e.g. `process.env["SOMETHING"]`.

An example in Next.js 14 using app router:

```
// file: env.tsx

import { unstable_noStore as noStore} from "next/cache";

export default function getEnv(name : string){
    noStore();
    return process.env[name];
}
```

`noStore()` is needed so that values will not be static.

page.tsx:

```
import getEnv from "./env";

export default function Page(){
    return getEnv("SOMETHING")
}
```

However this method only applies to the html returned from the server, it won't apply to the JavaScript bundle. Therefore, trying to access them in JavaScript code will always return `undefined`, as by nature variables/configs are fixed during build process and can't be changed after that.

Another way is to create an API so the client can fetch the updated data. Although, this will cost extra round trip to the server which I don't prefer it, so a workaround is to sneak these variables:

layout.tsx:

```
import getEnv from "./env";
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-something={getEnv("SOMETHING")}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

To access it just `document.documentElement.dataset.something`. It's better to create a new root layout to avoid all pages being dynamically rendered.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

**Note: The server must be restarted after any modifications to env variables.**

Answer (score 0):

I use React.js with typescript to deploy kubernates, and also change environment variables according to your environment dev, test or prod in helm charts.

```
1- public/config/config.js
  window.env = {
   MESSAGE: "helloworld"
  }

2- index.html inside head tag
<script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config/config.js"></script> 

3- inside index.tsx
declare global{
 interface Window {
  env: any;  
 }
}

4- In any page in project you can use simply
const msg = {
 message: window.env.MESSAGE
};
```

Hopes it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

When running things on the server, using `process.env.MY_API_ENDPOINT` is fine. E.g.

```
// route.ts
const url = `https://my-domain.net/${process.env.MY_API_ENDPOINT}/data`;
const response = await fetch(url);
```

You can also make a server config file and keep an object there will all your env vars, and then reference that object and the property you want.

It's only when you have env vars that are meant to run on the client, which are prefixed `NEXT_PUBLIC_` that you need to rebuild the app, since these are inlined at build time.

At most hosting services, you should be able to configure the env vars when you deploy, such that you can make different environments for different deployments.